# Check for missing default case in switch statement

Tags: c#, resharper, switch-statement, default

For ReSharper 6.1, there is no built-in inspection item for missing default statements within a switch for C#, however the custom patterns seem generally robust. I've messed around with them a bit for cases like missing else statements for if blocks, but I'm not sure how to do a check for missing default.

Here's what I have so far:

**Search Pattern**

```
switch($expr$)
{
    case $val$:
        $statement$
        break;
    $missingDefault$
}
```

**Replacement Pattern**

```
switch($expr$)
{
    case $val$:
        $statement$
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Where $expr$ is an expression, $val is an expression, $statement$ is any number of statements, and $missingDefault$ is a maximum of 0 statements.

The problems here are the following:

- We can have any number of cases, which are themselves a collection made up of one or more statements (case + break, etc.) and any number of expressions
- For search pattern matching, we should only match against occurrences where there is nothing after the last case (ie. no default)
- We need the 'break' in the search pattern such that we can define nonexistence of statements thereafter. This break is required by the compiler, anyway.

Obviously, this search pattern only matches against occurrences containing a *single case and no default*, so is relatively useless. I need a pattern that will match against switches with *any number of cases*, any number of which may or may not contain a break (except the last case) and can contain any number of statements, and no default.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just to clarify, what is your purpose in adding the 'empty' default:
        break; statement?

Comment: given that your replacement code will mean Resharper will highlight it as `Redundant empty default switch branch`

Comment: the point is to have a default, such that there is at least a baseline. the fact that resharper will flag this as redundant is fine, as it's too highly dependent on the context to offer logic before the break.

Comment: I think having an empty default can be seen as a way of at least having thought about that it might happen. Although this makes me think whether doing "nothing" is fine in that case, maybe throwing an appropriate exception would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a good crack at this and I don't believe it is currently possible (Resharper 7)

Having said that you can always ask on the [Resharper forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper)

The only thing I can provide that *may* be of any use is the pattern to find

1) all switch statements

```
switch($expr$)
    $statement$
```

2) the switch statements that end in `default; break`:

```
switch($expr$)
{
    $statement$
    default:
    break;
}
```

You could then use the difference of these two lists to determine which ones are missing the `default;break;` statement. For example in my project I have 231 occurrences of the first and only 58 of the second.

I realise this is a *long* way off what you wanted (no replace!) but its the best I can muster.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with ReSharper's search patterns.
(And please note that *default* can be placed between *case* statements.)

Maybe ***Visual Studio*'s *Find and Replace*** can help you with option *Use **Regular expressions***.